# Assembly.LoadFile equivalent in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, reflection, rtti

I'm trying to load a program (.exe) written in Delphi 2010, so I can perform reflection in it. I've got the code to perform the reflection in Delphi, however, I can't seem to find examples or documentation on how to load a compiled binary, so I can do the reflection. All the examples and documentation show reflection being done to classes in the same project.

I know in C#, I'd just use

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile('path')
```

and then reflect on the assembly. Does Delphi have an equivalent Assembly class?

**UPDATE:**

I ended up not going the reflection or manifest route, I wrote a Delphi dll that gets all the data I need and DllImported the necessary functions. It's far less painful and my go-to method when UI Automation or Win32 can't detect or correctly detect certain UI components.

Comment: What you are planning isn't possible. Delphi RTTI acts in process. The target code needs to be running in the same process which performs the reflection.

Comment: Ok, thanks David. That I didn't know. Now it all makes a whole lot of sense.

Comment: I assume it is somehow possible to find, extract and then interpret the RTTI data (if any) in an .exe, but I guess it is not simple.and probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: I've read that before, using something like IDR. I'm exploring just reading the resources, since the DFM is in there, so I can get all the form information I need, so I don't have to do reflection.

Comment: You need to explain what it is you want to achieve. The term 'reflection' does not explain anything. Do you just want to read info on the app, do you want to add functionality. If you list the exact problem you want to solve I think you can advice you much better.

Comment: Ok. I am developing a small UI automation utility to automate software written in Delphi. The software I'm automating loads its controls dynamically at runtime. So, I wanted to use reflection to get access to the controls at runtime. To answer you specifically, read-only, to check that the control is on the screen at that point in the test.

Comment: If the application was done using VCL then you could get forms component structure by enumerating all child windows of the form as all visual components create their own windows for their controls. As for reading the DFM it won't help you since it is quite possible that DFM only contains information for the components placed on the form during the design time.

Comment: Thanks @SilverWarior for making that point. I've tried that using the Win32API and Microsoft UI automation. The problem is I couldn't get the name of each component, just the class name, so after enumerating, I'd get 3 TEdits with no way of differentiating between them, apart maybe from using the location/rectangle. My Plan B was using the DFM file at runtime.